# Initial Questions checkbox default

Tags: dspace

Could someone please point me to clues to how I can get the Initial Questions of Multiple titles: and Published: (yes, those are turned on in our 5.6 build) to show without the checked attribute by default?

We want <input name="multiple_titles" type="checkbox" value="true"> without checked.

I'm pretty new to DSpace and Mirage2. Cheers! Dave.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can override the following code to solve this issue.

```
submissionItem.setMultipleFiles(true);
submissionItem.setMultipleTitles(true);
submissionItem.setPublishedBefore(true);
```

in  https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-5_x/dspace-api/src/main/java/org/dspace/submit/step/SkipInitialQuestionsStep.java#L52-L55

Since this is in dspace-api, you can create a customized version of the file in your additions module.